# Why calendar multiple classes lack the blue triangle at the bottom right?

Tags: javascript

I have an exercise panel. In this panel there is a calendar. Sometimes customers pay on the day they come to exercise. I want to show this on the calendar. I want to show they that come here and they paid me on the same day. I have added a class to show the customer's payment, but it doesn't work correctly. If the customer pays on the day of exercise, it should be blue under the green. If he's just exercising, he must be completely green. If he didn't exercise, it must be completely red. If he paid on the day he wasn't exercising, his red should be blue at the bottom right.

How can I do this?

(The problem is javascript, not CSS.)

https://jsfiddle.net/nick_zoum/u5r279qz/

There are codes on the link. The HTML section shows the calendar that appears when it doesn't work. 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 10 should be blue at the bottom right. But some not. That is the problem.

```
for (var ix = 0; ix < kirmizilar.length; ix++) {
    if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), kirmizilar[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix])) {
        m = '<div class="kirmizi_odemetakvim">';
        break;
    }
    else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), kirmizilar[ix])) {
        m = '<div class="kirmizi">';
        break;
    }
}
for (var ix = 0; ix < yesiller.length; ix++) {
    if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), yesiller[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix])) {
        m = '<div class="yesil_odemetakvim">';
        break;
    }
    else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), yesiller[ix])) {
        m = '<div class="yesil">';
        break;
    }
}
for (var ix = 0; ix < turuncular.length; ix++) {
    if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), turuncular[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix])) {
        m = '<div class="turuncu_odemetakvim">';
        break;
    }
    else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), turuncular[ix])) {
        m = '<div class="turuncu">';
        break;
    }
}
for (var ix = 0; ix < koyumaviler.length; ix++) {
    if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), koyumaviler[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix])) {
        m = '<div class="koyumavi_odemetakvim">';
        break;
    }
    else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), koyumaviler[ix])) {
        m = '<div class="koyumavi">';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem? What's the expected result? Which blocks in the example should have a different color?

Comment: 6, 7, 8, 10 must be like 3, 4, 5 @nickzoum

Comment: Please add jQuery to the Fiddle.

Comment: @MehmetCanErtanLastOfDead `6,7,9,10` are not in `yesiller` array and only dates in `yesiller` array can have the `yesil_odemetakvim` class. `8`: `yesiller[3]` is `2019/8/8` but `odemeler[3]` is `2019/8/10`, so `ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), yesiller[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix])` will never be true for `8`

Comment: @MehmetCanErtanLastOfDead your fiddle has an error of ReferenceError: $ is not defined, which makes me think that jQuery is not properly added to it.

Comment: @LajosArpad I really have no idea. I'm new to these. Let me tell you. All dates there should be blue at the bottom right. But some don't. That is the problem.

Comment: You need to make sure that your yesil_odemetakvim class is applied to all dates where it should be applied. Should it be applied for all the green dates, all the colored dates, or even the white dates?

Comment: (Did you actually write this yourself? Asking because of those weird function names, that rather looks like the code might have been “obfuscated” at some point already. And if you _did_ write it yourself, then it would be preferable if you showed a version using function names that make _some_ sense in relation to what their purpose is.)

Comment: @misorude I didn't write it myself. I just set it up for myself.

Comment: @misorude LajosArpad I added something new. Will you look?

Comment: @MehmetCanErtanLastOfDead Pretty sure I solved the problem, check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that some elements were at the wrong index so you had to check if they existed in the array rather than checking if they are at that index. I also turned the whole thing into a loop to avoid repetition.

This is the part that changed:

```
[
    ["kirmizi", kirmizilar],
    ["yesil", yesiller],
    ["turuncu", turuncular],
    ["koyumavi", koyumaviler]
].some(function (group) {
    return group[1].some(function (date) {
        if (ggg(currentDate, date)) {
            return m = odemeler.includes(dateToString(currentDate)) ? `<div class="${group[0]}_odemetakvim">` : `<div class="${group[0]}">`;
        }
    });
});
```

And here is a working snippet:

```js
var kirmizilar = ['2019/8/6'];
var yesiller = ['2019/8/3', '2019/8/4', '2019/8/5', '2019/8/8'];
var turuncular = ['2019/8/7'];
var koyumaviler = ['2019/8/10'];
var odemeler = ['2019/8/3', '2019/8/4', '2019/8/5', '2019/8/10', '2019/8/6', '2019/8/7', '2019/8/8', '2019/8/9'];
$(function() {
  function c() {
    p();
    var e = h();
    var r = 0;
    var u = false;
    l.empty();
    while (!u) {
      if (s[r] == e[0].weekday) {
        u = true
      } else {
        l.append('<div class="blank"></div>');
        r++
      }
    }
    for (var c = 0; c < 42 - r; c++) {
      if (c >= e.length) {
        l.append('<div class="blank"></div>')
      } else {
        var v = e[c].day;
        var m = g(new Date(t, n - 1, v)) ? '<div>' : "<div>";
        var iod = 0;

        var currentDate = new Date(t, n - 1, v);

        if (!([
            ["kirmizi", kirmizilar],
            ["yesil", yesiller],
            ["turuncu", turuncular],
            ["koyumavi", koyumaviler]
          ].some(function(group) {
            return group[1].some(function(date) {
              if (ggg(currentDate, date)) {
                return m = odemeler.includes(dateToString(currentDate)) ? `<div class="${group[0]}_odemetakvim">` : `<div class="${group[0]}">`;
              }
            });
          })) && odemeler.includes(dateToString(currentDate))) {
          m = `<div class="odemetakvim">`;
        }
        l.append(m + "" + v + "</div>")
      }
    }
    var y = o[n - 1];
    a.css("background-color", y).find("h1").text(i[n - 1] + " " + t);
    f.find("div").css("color", y);
    d()
  }

  function h() {
    var e = [];
    for (var r = 1; r < v(t, n) + 1; r++) {
      e.push({
        day: r,
        weekday: s[m(t, n, r)]
      })
    }
    return e
  }

  function p() {
    f.empty();
    for (var e = 0; e < 7; e++) {
      f.append("<div>" + s[e].substring(0, 3) + "</div>")
    }
  }

  function d() {
    var t;
    var n = $("#calendar").css("width", e + "px");
    n.find(t = "#calendar_weekdays, #calendar_content").css("width", e + "px").find("div").css({
      width: e / 7 + "px",
      height: e / 7 + "px",
      "line-height": e / 7 + "px"
    });
    n.find("#calendar_header").css({
      height: e * (1 / 7) + "px"
    }).find('i[class^="icon-chevron"]').css("line-height", e * (1 / 7) + "px")
  }

  function v(e, t) {
    return (new Date(e, t, 0)).getDate()
  }

  function m(e, t, n) {
    return (new Date(e, t - 1, n)).getDay()
  }

  function g(e) {
    return dateToString(new Date) == dateToString(e)
  }

  function ggg(loopDate, arrayDate) {
    return dateToString(loopDate) == arrayDate
  }

  function dateToString(e) {
    return e.getFullYear() + "/" + (e.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + e.getDate()
  }

  function b() {
    var e = new Date;
    t = e.getFullYear();
    n = e.getMonth() + 1
  }
  var e = 480;
  var t = 2013;
  var n = 9;
  var r = [];
  var i = ["OCAK", "ŞUBAT", "MART", "NISAN", "MAYIS", "HAZIRAN", "TEMMUZ", "AĞUSTOS", "EYLÜL", "EKIM", "KASIM", "ARALIK"];
  var s = ["Pazar", "Pzt", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cmt"];
  var o = ["#16a085", "#1abc9c", "#c0392b", "#27ae60", "#FF6860", "#f39c12", "#f1c40f", "#e67e22", "#2ecc71", "#e74c3c", "#d35400", "#2c3e50"];
  var u = $("#calendar");
  var a = u.find("#calendar_header");
  var f = u.find("#calendar_weekdays");
  var l = u.find("#calendar_content");
  b();
  c();
  a.find('i[class^="icon-chevron"]').on("click", function() {
    var e = $(this);
    var r = function(e) {
      n = e == "next" ? n + 1 : n - 1;
      if (n < 1) {
        n = 12;
        t--
      } else if (n > 12) {
        n = 1;
        t++
      }
      c()
    };
    if (e.attr("class").indexOf("left") != -1) {
      r("previous")
    } else {
      r("next")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F5F1E9;
}

#calendar {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 320px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#calendar_weekdays div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#calendar_content,
#calendar_weekdays,
#calendar_header {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
}

#calendar_weekdays div,
#calendar_content div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #787878;
}

#calendar_content {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
}

#calendar_content div {
  float: left;
}

#calendar_content div:hover {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

#calendar_content div.blank {
  background-color: #d3d1ff;
}

#calendar_header,
#calendar_content div.today {
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#calendar_content div.today {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#calendar_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF6860;
  padding: 18px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
}

#calendar_header h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

i[class^=icon-chevron] {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#calendar *,
#calendar *:before,
#calendar *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  box-sizing: content-box !important;
}

#calendar_content div.kirmizi {
  background-color: rgb(231, 76, 60);
  color: white;
}

#calendar_content div.yesil {
  background-color: rgb(135, 211, 124);
  color: white;
}

#calendar_content div.turuncu {
  background-color: rgb(232, 150, 0);
  color: white;
}

#calendar_content div.koyumavi {
  background-color: rgb(72, 61, 139);
  color: white;
}

#calendar_content div.odemetakvim {
  background-color: rgb(34, 167, 240);
  color: white;
}

#calendar_content div.yesil_odemetakvim {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(34, 167, 240) 32%, rgb(135, 211, 124) 32%);
  color: white;
}

#calendar_content div.kirmizi_odemetakvim {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(34, 167, 240) 32%, rgb(231, 76, 60) 32%);
  color: white;
}

#calendar_content div.turuncu_odemetakvim {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(34, 167, 240) 32%, rgb(232, 150, 0) 32%);
  color: white;
}

#calendar_content div.koyumavi_odemetakvim {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(34, 167, 240) 32%, rgb(72, 61, 139) 32%);
  color: white;
}

.calendar-info {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.calendar-info img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.calendar-info span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar" style="margin: unset; width: 480px;">
  <div id="calendar_header" style="background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34); height: 68.5714px;">
    <i class="icon-chevron-left" style="line-height: 68.5714px;"></i>
    <h1>AĞUSTOS 2019</h1>
    <i class="icon-chevron-right" style="line-height: 68.5714px;"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="calendar_weekdays" style="width: 480px;">
    <div style="color: rgb(230, 126, 34); width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">Paz</div>
    <div style="color: rgb(230, 126, 34); width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">Pzt</div>
    <div style="color: rgb(230, 126, 34); width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">Sal</div>
    <div style="color: rgb(230, 126, 34); width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">Çar</div>
    <div style="color: rgb(230, 126, 34); width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">Per</div>
    <div style="color: rgb(230, 126, 34); width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">Cum</div>
    <div style="color: rgb(230, 126, 34); width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">Cmt</div>
  </div>
  <div id="calendar_content" style="width: 480px;">
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">1</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">2</div>
    <div class="yesil_odemetakvim" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">3</div>
    <div class="yesil_odemetakvim" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">4</div>
    <div class="yesil_odemetakvim" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">5</div>
    <div class="kirmizi" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">6</div>
    <div class="turuncu" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">7</div>
    <div class="yesil" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">8</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">9</div>
    <div class="koyumavi" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">10</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">11</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">12</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">13</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">14</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">15</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">16</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">17</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">18</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">19</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">20</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">21</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">22</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">23</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">24</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">25</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">26</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">27</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">28</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">29</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">30</div>
    <div style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;">31</div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
    <div class="blank" style="width: 68.5714px; height: 68.5714px; line-height: 68.5714px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is ES6 and not ES5, so if you want Internet Explorer support you will have to replace `some` with a `for` loop and `includes` with `indexOf`. I hope doing those changes will give you a better understanding of how the code works now, and what the problem was.

Comment: This answer better than. Perfect. I'm so glad I could explain myself.

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted.

Comment: I have a problem. I noticed the days when the customer came to only pay were white. But it must be blue. So, if the customer has just come to pay, the background must be completely blue. How to fix this? @LajosArpad

Comment: @MehmetCanErtanLastOfDead Think I fixed it, please check the updated answer. (Added `'2019/8/9'` to `odemeler` list to test it)

Comment: Yes. It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this code:

```
            for (var ix = 0; ix < turuncular.length; ix++) {

                if ( ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), turuncular[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix]) ) {

                    m = '<div class="turuncu_odemetakvim">';

                    break;

                }
                else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), turuncular[ix])) {

                    m = '<div class="turuncu">';

                    break;
                }

            }
```

This is adding if `ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), turuncular[ix])` is true. If `ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix])` is also true, then the class to be added is `turuncu_odemetakvim`. Otherwise, it's `turuncu`. The five meaningful class names, if they end with _odematakvim, then they have that blue triangle at the bottom. Otherwise, they do not have that. If we standardize that ending for any case, then all the items will have that blue triangle:

```
var kirmizilar = ['2019/8/6'];
var yesiller = ['2019/8/3', '2019/8/4', '2019/8/5', '2019/8/8'];
var turuncular = ['2019/8/7'];
var koyumaviler = ['2019/8/10'];
var odemeler = ['2019/8/3', '2019/8/4', '2019/8/5', '2019/8/10', '2019/8/6', '2019/8/7', '2019/8/8'];

$(function() {    

    function c() {

        p();

        var e = h();

        var r = 0;

        var u = false;

        l.empty();

        while (!u) {

            if (s[r] == e[0].weekday) {

                u = true

            } else {

                l.append('<div class="blank"></div>');

                r++

            }

        }

        for (var c = 0; c < 42 - r; c++) {

            if (c >= e.length) {

                l.append('<div class="blank"></div>')

            } else {

                var v = e[c].day;

                var m = g(new Date(t, n - 1, v)) ? '<div>' : "<div>";

                var iod = 0;



                for (var ix = 0; ix < kirmizilar.length; ix++) {

                    if ( ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), kirmizilar[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix]) ) {

                        m = '<div class="kirmizi_odemetakvim">';

                        break;

                    }
                    else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), kirmizilar[ix])) {

                        m = '<div class="kirmizi_odemetakvim">';

                        break;
                    }

                }



                for (var ix = 0; ix < yesiller.length; ix++) {

                    if ( ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), yesiller[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix]) ) {

                        m = '<div class="yesil_odemetakvim">';

                        break;

                    }
                    else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), yesiller[ix])) {

                        m = '<div class="yesil_odemetakvim">';

                        break;
                    }

                }

                for (var ix = 0; ix < turuncular.length; ix++) {

                    if ( ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), turuncular[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix]) ) {

                        m = '<div class="turuncu_odemetakvim">';

                        break;

                    }
                    else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), turuncular[ix])) {

                        m = '<div class="turuncu_odemetakvim">';

                        break;
                    }

                }
                for (var ix = 0; ix < koyumaviler.length; ix++) {

                    if ( ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), koyumaviler[ix]) && ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), odemeler[ix]) ) {

                        m = '<div class="koyumavi_odemetakvim">';

                        break;

                    }
                    else if (ggg(new Date(t, n - 1, v), koyumaviler[ix])) {

                        m = '<div class="koyumavi_odemetakvim"">';

                        break;
                    }

                }

                l.append(m + "" + v + "</div>")

            }

        }

        var y = o[n - 1];

        a.css("background-color", y).find("h1").text(i[n - 1] + " " + t);

        f.find("div").css("color", y);

        d()

    }



    function h() {

        var e = [];

        for (var r = 1; r < v(t, n) + 1; r++) {

            e.push({

                day: r,

                weekday: s[m(t, n, r)]

            })

        }

        return e

    }



    function p() {

        f.empty();

        for (var e = 0; e < 7; e++) {

            f.append("<div>" + s[e].substring(0, 3) + "</div>")

        }

    }



    function d() {

        var t;

        var n = $("#calendar").css("width", e + "px");

        n.find(t = "#calendar_weekdays, #calendar_content").css("width", e + "px").find("div").css({

            width: e / 7 + "px",

            height: e / 7 + "px",

            "line-height": e / 7 + "px"

        });

        n.find("#calendar_header").css({

            height: e * (1 / 7) + "px"

        }).find('i[class^="icon-chevron"]').css("line-height", e * (1 / 7) + "px")

    }



    function v(e, t) {

        return (new Date(e, t, 0)).getDate()

    }



    function m(e, t, n) {

        return (new Date(e, t - 1, n)).getDay()

    }



    function g(e) {

        return y(new Date) == y(e)

    }



    function ggg(loopDate, arrayDate) {

        return y(loopDate) == arrayDate

    }



    function y(e) {

        return e.getFullYear() + "/" + (e.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + e.getDate()

    }



    function b() {

        var e = new Date;

        t = e.getFullYear();

        n = e.getMonth() + 1

    }

    var e = 480;

    var t = 2013;

    var n = 9;

    var r = [];

    var i = ["OCAK", "ŞUBAT", "MART", "NISAN", "MAYIS", "HAZIRAN", "TEMMUZ", "AĞUSTOS", "EYLÜL", "EKIM", "KASIM", "ARALIK"];

    var s = ["Pazar", "Pzt", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cmt"];

    var o = ["#16a085", "#1abc9c", "#c0392b", "#27ae60", "#FF6860", "#f39c12", "#f1c40f", "#e67e22", "#2ecc71", "#e74c3c", "#d35400", "#2c3e50"];

    var u = $("#calendar");

    var a = u.find("#calendar_header");

    var f = u.find("#calendar_weekdays");

    var l = u.find("#calendar_content");

    b();

    c();

    a.find('i[class^="icon-chevron"]').on("click", function() {

        var e = $(this);

        var r = function(e) {

            n = e == "next" ? n + 1 : n - 1;

            if (n < 1) {

                n = 12;

                t--

            } else if (n > 12) {

                n = 1;

                t++

            }

            c()

        };

        if (e.attr("class").indexOf("left") != -1) {

            r("previous")

        } else {

            r("next")

        }

    })

})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tL9hu3y8/1/